# CORS Error in Meteor JS while using Twit API

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, twitter, cors

When I tried to use twit 'search/tweets' in my meteor js Application, I get this error. How do I enable CORS on my local host??

> Failed to load
>   https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?count=100: Response to
>   preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 400.

Comment: You're trying to make a secure request via a non-secure URL (localhost) and the API is blocking the request. I'm not sure how Meteor works, but I'm certain that there's a way to proxy your request in order to avoid the CORS issue.

Comment: Share some code, please

Comment: Add twitter tag

Answer (score 0):

Browers' xhr requests implement CORS but servers' http requests don't. You need to proxy the request to twitter via your server. Set up a route on your server to make a http request to  the twitter api.